# OrderBy custom comparer specific letters before numbers

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

Say I have the following List:

```
var lettersAndNumbers = new List<string> { "5", "kl", "1", "st", "3" };
```

How do I use `OrderBy` to sort the list, where I can specify that `kl` should be the first item, `st` the next, and the remaining sequence should be ordered by numbers lowest to highest?

I know that I need to use a custom `comparer`. I have tried and created a `comparer` class implementing `ICompareable`, but I can't seem to make it work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `comparer` to achieve this. Just try something like this:

```
var res = lettersAndNumbers.OrderBy(c => !int.TryParse(c, out var temp) ? c : 
                                         temp.ToString("D10"))
                                        .OrderBy(c=> !char.IsDigit(c[0]) ? 0 : 1).ToList();
```